# Visual Studio 2015 c++ environment variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx) guide, I'm trying to execute vcvarsall.bat ... but nothing happens. I looking into my "Environment Variables" dialog (under System / Advanced System settings) , and I don't see anything new added there (I expecting to find there INCLUDE variable).

What I'm missing?

Windows 10, VS 2015 Pro

Comment: ***What I'm missing?*** Are you running this from a command prompt and looking at the variables using the set command in the command prompt? You can not run this from explorer and the variables will only change in the command prompt not the system environment.

Comment: ***I looking into my "Enviroment Variables" dialog (under System / Advanced System settings)*** The system environment will not be affected by the environment you added in the command prompt running the vcvarsall.bat script.

Comment: Each process on the system has its own environment - you can't change the environment for one and expect another to see the change. You can, however, change the environment in one shell and expect child-processes to see it since the environment is (to some extend) inherited. What you are missing is an understanding of how environment variables work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm missing? Are you running this from a command prompt and looking at the variables using the set command in the command prompt? You can not run this from explorer and the variables will only change in the command prompt not the system environment.

This comment is the answer. vcvarsall.bat is a batch file that exports environment variables. These values can pollute the environment namespace if they're at the system level, which can cause some weird things to happen. Instead, you will need to fire up a command prompt, and then run this batch file in the same prompt, where you will then compile from the command line here.

e.g. if you were doing this in your own batch file you would

- include the vcvarsall.bat file to get the build environment variables
- call msbuild on your project/solution files